# XSLT external param split

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xsl transformation and so I've been researching on how to do this for a while now, I am trying to get an external parameter into an xsl which is a concatenated list of names separated by a comma and then split that parameter, I have an xml as follows:

```
<root>
  <contacts>
    <contact>   
        <name></name>       
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name></name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name></name>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

This is my xsl so far, my external parameter is called EXT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:param name="EXT"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name/text()" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </name>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So for instance I'm receiving a parameter such as "John,Peter,Jack" the desired result being:

```
    <root>
  <contacts>
    <contact>   
        <name>John</name>       
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Jack</name>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

The closest I've been to this result is something like:

```
    <root>
  <contacts>
    <contact>   
        <name>John</name>
        <name>Peter</name>  
        <name>Jack</name>   
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name></name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name></name>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You really need to describe this and tag it as an XSLT 1.0 problem. With XSLT 2.0 the solution would be trivial. Are you sure you can't use 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's okay for you to also hard-code the `contact` element, you can simply add them to your result. This is only a minimal change:

```
<xsl:template match="contacts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$EXT"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <contact>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                </name>
            </contact>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <contact>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                </name>
            </contact>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This creates the desired output.